# Communicating Between UI thread and user thread in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, delegates, ui-thread

First I have created a SampleClass as below:

```
Public Class SampleClass
    Public a As String
    Public b As Integer
    Public Sub New(ByVal str1 As String, ByVal int1 As Integer)
        Me.a = str1
        Me.b = int1
    End Sub
    Public Sub TestSub()
        Me.a = Me.a & " done"
        Me.b += 3
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then I have created a Form named MyForm which has two buttons name Button1 and Button2 and 3 TextBoxes named TextBox1, TextBox2 and TextBox3.

```
Imports System.Threading
Public Class MyForm
    Dim MyArray() As Integer
    Dim I As Integer   
    Dim x As SampleClass, X1 As SampleClass
    Dim t() As Thread
    Dim ThreadIndex As Integer
    Private Sub MyForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ThreadIndex = -1
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            x = New SampleClass("First Part", 1)
            X1 = New SampleClass("Next Part", 2)
            ThreadIndex = ThreadIndex + 1
            t(ThreadIndex) = New Thread(AddressOf UpdateText)
            t.Start(x)
            If TextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
                Me.TextBox1.Invoke(New MyDel(AddressOf UpdateText), x)
            Else                
                Me.TextBox1.Text = x.a 
                Me.TextBox2.Text = x.b
            End If
            ThreadIndex = ThreadIndex + 1
            t(ThreadIndex) = New Thread(AddressOf UpdateText)
            t1.Start(X1)
            If TextBox3.InvokeRequired Then
                Me.TextBox3.Invoke(New MyDel(AddressOf UpdateText), X1)
            Else
                Me.TextBox3.Text = X1.a 
            End If
        Catch ex As ThreadStartException

        End Try
    End Sub   
    Private Sub UpdateText(Temp As Object)        
        Temp.TestSub()        
    End Sub
    Private Delegate Sub MyDel(Temp As Object)
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        StopThread()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StopThread()    
        Dim Counter as Integer, I as Integer
        Try
              Counter = 0
              For I = 0 to ThreadIndex
                  If t(I).IsAlive then
                     T(I).Abort()
                     Counter = Counter + 1
                  End If
              Next
        Catch Ex as ThreadAbortException
        Finally
              ThreadIndex = ThreadIndex - Counter
        End Try
    End Sub
 End Class
```

This code is running smooth and fine as long as the TestSub is not taking time to complete. In my original case, It takes some time to complete as it has lots of works to do. There I am Facing the problem.

Suppose the TestSub is working on the thread and it takes say 1 minute to do something and then it deduces the values of variable a and b.

When I am calling the delegate with parameters, UI is not waiting for the thread to produce the values of a and b, instead it's updating the initial values of a and b in the textboxes though the thread is running.

Is there any way I can make my UI to wait till the user thread to complete its work and produce new values of variables a and b while also the UI will be available to user to do other works i.e. while waiting for the user thread, the UI can be accessed by user for other works?

Another question, when I am clicking on the Button2 to stop the thread, it's generating MessageBox as "Thread is aborted" which I don't want to show. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Why are you checking if invocation is required in the `Load` event? That is already thread-safe.

Comment: Don't ever ever ever call `Thread.Abort()` **unless** you are trying to force and exit on your app. Aborting threads can leave your AppDomain in an undefined state.